# How to open popup based on url?

Tags: angularjs

I have show details button:

```
<button class="details" ng-click="ShowDetail(pin)"></button>
```

When user click that button it calls api(json) and then shows me partial view with data for that specific pin, but in url is notting happend. My question is how to pass parameters in url and then when user open that url to get that partial view with data from that specific pin.

Comment: You need to use at least ngRoute for routes support. Or ui router, then you will be able to set up this route/state which has view displaying as popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using the $stateProvider for this. See our implementation:

```
angular.module('edo.zending', ['ui.router', 'ui.date', 'ngResource']).config(function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('root.zending', {
      url: "/zending/{zendingId}/{documentId}",
      // Setting value: null makes the parameter optional
      params: {
        zendingId: {
          value: null
        },
        documentId: {
          value: null
        }
      },
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/zending/views/zending.html',
          controller: 'ZendingCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

});
```

My URL can now be: .../zending or .../zending/1 or .../zending/1/1 (using any number or value)

in my controller i can now use these params as followed

```
$scope.zendingId = $rootScope.$stateParams.zendingId;
$scope.documentId = $rootScope.$stateParams.documentId;
```

You can apply this same principle to your needs.

Note: it is very hard to give you a fitting answer when you provide very limited information

Comment: i need ui-router for this?